# Is RoleProvider not longer available in C# Framework 4.0?

Tags: c#, sql, c#-4.0, roleprovider

I've a Custom `RoleProvider` created sometime ago, and wanting to change the library to use the .NET Framework 4. Once changed, I am loosing the reference to `RoleProvider` class. Has something changed since 3.5 for `RoleProvider`? It seems to have disappeared.

Anyone know the new way to create these in C# 4.0, or do I need to revert back to C# 3.5 and rely on the v2.0 library for `System.Web.Security`?

Or do I now need to use `SqlRoleProvider` instead, even though I use a different db than SQL?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The assembly has changed from System.Web (in System.Web.dll) (in .NET 3.5 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider(v=VS.90).aspx) to System.Web.ApplicationServices (in System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll) (in .NET 4.0 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider(v=VS.100).aspx)

You need to reference the new assembly.